# How to remove this Apache page from my localhost address?

Tags: apache, server, localhost

I was trying to get the Apache server to work. When I was done with it I uninstalled the service and deleted all the server files. However I noticed even after all that going to `localhost` address shows me this page

[image: localhost]

How do I go on about removing this page from my localhost? Thanks

Comment: This means you still have (at least one) httpd running.  Kill that httpd server, free up port 80 and it will be fine.  If a process has loaded all it requires into memory, you can delete the files and the process will be ok to keep running.

Comment: I tired using `netstat -a` and there isn't anything running on port 80. Moreover when I open the `localhost:80` address on Chrome I get the "Unable to connect" which is weird. The page only shows up when I open `localhost:80` on Firefox. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the previous comment ... after killing all httpd processes (and this may be a problem because Apache will respawn children) ... then reboot the system to see if the problem persists.

If it does persist, then Apache has not been uninstalled and it'll have to be uninstalled.  If the system uses sysvinit, look in /etc/init.d for a script that starts Apache and disable that script.

If the problem does not persist then Apache was properly uninstalled and the problem will not recur.

Comment: I tired using netstat -a and there isn't anything running on port 80. Moreover when I open the localhost:80 address on Chrome I get the "Unable to connect" which is weird. The page only shows up when I open localhost:80 on Firefox. Any clue?

Comment: In that case, it's likely that Firefox has the page cached.  Try flushing the Firefox caches (both memory and disk) and then check it again.